# python-docx save attribute read-only

Tags: python

So, again, I must start off apologising for the fact I am a complete newbie to Linux, Python and coding as a whole.

I have installed `python-docx` to do a very simple task:

```py
import shutil
from docx import Document

name = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
source_path = r'/home/tye/Documents/xxxxxxxxxx/'
template = r'template_xx'

shutil.copytree(source_path+template, source_path+name)
document = Document(source_path+name+'/correspondence/initial.docx')
paragraph = document.add_paragraph ('helloworld')
document.save=(source_path+name+'/correspondence/initial.docx')
```

whilst the folder copying bit works fine, the add paragraph doesn't. I get the same message each time:

> 'Document' object attribute 'save' is read-only'

I have tried running the file using sudo in the bash terminal, I have tried changing the user permissions on the document. I know I must be doing something incredibly simple wrong but I just can't figure out what :(

Grateful for any help...

ps, I have googled this loads of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Linux file system permissions, but is just a syntactical mistake in your code.

Look at the last line:

```py
document.save=(source_path+name+'/correspondence/initial.docx')
```

This makes the interpreter try to assign the string produced by `source_path+name+'/correspondence/initial.docx'` to the object variable `save` of the `document` object.

That is forbidden, because `document.save` is protected against overwriting it, which would make no sense by the way.

What you want instead is to **call the function** with the string as argument!
To do this, you just need to remove the `=` symbol:

```py
document.save(source_path+name+'/correspondence/initial.docx')
```

More documentation for `docx.Document.save` can be found [here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.save).

Comment: Thanks so much. It's pretty obvious when someone points it out but I would never have thought of that. Just have to figure out how to mark the questions solved...